# GPU profiling shows inadequite times for Present

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx, profiling

I'm profiling my application with GPU profiler that comes with Visual Studio 2015. Application performs rendering with DX11 / D2D using waitable swap chain. Application also does basic profiling by calling QueryPerformanceCounter before rendering starts, after rendering finishes, after present finishes and after wait for presentation finishes. I've tried to track down cases when rendering takes too long (usually it only takes less than 1 ms, but sometimes jumps to 20 ms and above) and used VS GPU profiler. Output from it is very confusing: rendering hiccups are not visible, and Present is always reported to happen when rendering of the next frame starts, no matter how long the delay is. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a problem on GPU? It can be CPU problem as well. Anyway, w/o code it's impossible to say.

Comment: I think i have a problem with GPU profiler.

Comment: You can try another. Ex, Intel GPA or nVidia nSight.